# google chrome switching off after 5 seconds

Tags: google-chrome

When I open Google Chrome, the home page appears on the desktop.  A box appears in the top right corner, that says restore pages.  No matter what I click, after approx. 5 seconds, Chrome closes.

I have uninstalled, and then reinstalled Chrome.  I have deleted the Chrome crash folder contents in programs, and searched my C drive to see if there is any chrome folders.  However, the behavior still persists; Chrome terminates after 5 seconds, with the restore page box in the corner.

Comment: Are your computer restricted somehow by sysadmin? Since when it start happening? You need to check the crash file and paste the backtrace. Please include what system you're using.

Answer (score -1):

Troubleshooting tips : Log in as another user on this PC (assuming you're in a multi-user environment) and see if Chrome acts differently.  Check the Windows event viewer to see if any useful errors show up there.  Do a reboot, in case there's a problem we're not aware of that's resolved by reboots.  Check to see if any other programs are having problems.
You can thoroughly uninstall by doing the regular uninstall, then, while logged in as your user, deleting Google Chrome related items in %AppData% and %TEMP% .  Beware that if you have Google Drive or other non-Chrome apps, you may accidentally break those.
By the way, this site is geared towards question-answer format.

Comment: The question was downvoted.  I've been downvoted as well, and I'd love to know why.  @Grum has attempted troubleshooting and provided some of his findings.  I provided some other information-gathering steps he can use to discover the root cause.  There's definitely better ways to ask questions, but simply burying new users makes them give up instead of joining the community.